# Create new Office document in SPO modern document library

Tags: document-library, content-type, document-template

I have a custom content type added to my document libraries (nearly a thousand) and want users to be able to easily create Word, Excel and PowerPoint documents in it via "new item".

However, after adding my own content type to the library, the following items disappear from the list:

[image: create menu]

In the picture you can see how it is supposed to be. But those items disappear if the default content type is removed and replaced with another one.
I could resolve this problem with just adding three new content types that are derived from my custom content type and give each of them another office template (.dotx-file).
But if a new document is added to the library now, the browser wants to open the *native app* automatically.
Before adding my custom content type, the default behaviour was using the internal Office WebApp.
How can I archive that the WebApp is always used?
Or even better: That the user can pick if he wants to create the new document with the native app or the browser app.  (In editing this option is always available. Here the user can chose "Edit in WebApp" or "Edit in native app". But on creation this seems not to be an option.

Any proposals?